# Grammar - Usage

Tags: grammaire

Could any one please tell me which of the following sentence is correct with respect to French Grammar usage

> En quoi la table est-elle ?

> En quoi est la table ?

Answer (score 2):

As far as grammar is concerned, your sentences are correct.

The first one doesn't sound very natural though. Staying formal, I'd rather expect:

> En quoi la table est-elle faite ?

or

> De quelle matière est faite la table ?

In everyday's French, you would more likely hear:

> Elle est faite en quoi, la table ?
> Elle est en quoi, la table ?
> La table, elle est en quoi ?

and other variants like

> C'est une table en quoi ? (Thanks @FredericS)

Comment: I think I would naturally say _C'est une table en quoi ?_ but all your everyday examples sound natural too

Comment: A brûle-pourpoint, je dirais "De quoi est faite la table ?"